# I am trying to show a Loader before Jquery Ajax call but it does not work

Tags: jquery, ajax, loader

I am trying to show a div that containers a loader before an ajax call using the following code.

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
  $("#div_loader").css("display", "block")
})

$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
  $("#div_loader").css("display", "none");
})
```

But I am only able to see the div when I debug the JS using Chrome developer Tools. But normally, it never shows up.

Div Html

```
<div class="loader" id='div_loader'>
            <div class="shade"></div>
            <div class="popup">
            </div>
        </div>
```

Css for the loader

```
.loader {
    position: absolute;
    /* height: 100%; */
    max-height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.shade {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 9999999999;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: #333;
    opacity: 0.8;
}

.loader .popup {
    position: fixed;
    height: 102px;
    width: 218px;
    background: url(../images/loader.gif) 50% 85% no-repeat;
    background-size: 32px;
    margin: 12% auto;
    border-radius: 6px;
    top: 10%;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 99999999999;
}
```

And here's the ajax request...

```
function AjaxPostCall(ServicePath, Input) {
    var data = $.parseJSON($.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: ServicePath,
        data: JSON.stringify({ 'Input': Input }),
        dataType: "json",
        async: false
    }).responseText); // This will wait until you get a response from the ajax request.
    var DataSet = JSON.parse(data.d);
    return DataSet;    
}
```

Comment: show us css and html of #div_loader, please

Comment: Please check now.  I have updated the post and added them as per your suggestion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have solved it. I was new to Jquery and I didn't know that setting async property of an ajax call to false shall freeze the page up until now. I have tried setting async to true and it's working fine now.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function () {
    blockUI();
})

$(document).ajaxComplete(function () {
    unBlockUI();
})


function blockUI() {
    var loader = '<div class="page-overlay"><div class="page-loader"></div></div>';

    $('#pageLoader').append(loader);
}

function unBlockUI() {
    $('#pageLoader').empty();
}



.page-loader {
    border: 5px solid #eee;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-top: 5px solid rgba(0,0,0,1);
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    -webkit-animation: spin 1s linear infinite;
    animation: spin 1s linear infinite;
    position: absolute;
    top: 300px;
    z-index: 9999;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
    left: 700px;
}

.page-overlay {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
    z-index: 9999;
    cursor: wait;
}


<div id="pageLoader"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this as example.

```js
$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
  $("#div_loader").css("display", "block")
});

$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
  $("#div_loader").css("display", "none");
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  $.ajax({url: "demo_test.txt", success: function(result){
            $("#div1").html(result);
  }});
});
```

```css
#div_loader
{
  background-color: #EEE;
  Color: #000;
  width:100%;
  height:500px;
  text-align:center;
  padding-top:100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="div_loader">Please wait...
</div>

<div id="div1">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this global event of ajax

```
    $(document).bind("ajaxSend", function(){
        $("#div_loader").css("display", "block");
     }).bind("ajaxComplete", function(){
        $("#div_loader").css("display", "none");
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what the problem is, without seeing all of the code, but many a times I have used a similar approach to below.

**HTML**

```
<div class='js-div-loader div-loader'></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.div-loader{
  width: 200px;
  height:200px;
  padding:10px;
  /*'Hide here, if you don't want to hide on page load' display:none;*/
}
```

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".js-div-loader").hide();

    $(document).ajaxStart(function() {
      $(".js-div-loader").show();
    })

    $(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
      $(".js-div-loader").hide();
    })
});
```

I prefer to use `class's` over `id's` - never a good idea to use the same `id` on multiple elements, "they" should be unique per document.

I always prepend a class with "js-" Helps me determine what selectors/elements are being used in `js`

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me out Tez. Actually, there is not much code left to share. It is a very basic program and I am not  having any element with duplicate Ids. The show and hide actually works but only when I debug using Chrome Developer Tools. When the page is run normally, the div just doesn't appear at all no matter how long it takes the ajax request to complete.